# "Reset this PC" stoping and going to boot options

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

So, I have two HDs, one internal and one external, i've had them for quite some time and needed to clean them, the external one was easy, and in there I have the Windows installer, now I need to clean the internal HD, but i don't really want to install Windows again, so i thought about the "Reset this PC", however at about one third of the reset, it just stops and goes to the Windows 10 boot options, I've tried many things at this point, they include: Scaning the entire internal HD looking for corrupted .dll files using `sfc /scannow` both on the command prompt run by administrator and the one on the boot options; set the computer to clean boot and tried to reset; disabled and enabled again the recovery environment agent using command prompt. None of those did anything and the reset still seems to stop at the same percentage (~31%).

Somethings worth mentioning are: My computer was filled with virus which I just recently scanned with MalwareBytes and (i think) deleted them all, if it is of any use, there were about 1500 detections; I haven't tried anything involving hardwares/physical parts; my PC was built, so if i did have to completely erase the internal HD, I'd also have to install a lot of drivers and programs; i'm using Windows 10.

Basically, I want to know what is causing the reset problem and how i can succesfully reset my PC. If possible i'd like to know if it is easier to reset the PC, just erase the internal HD, or some other option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cave and pave, reinstall the OS clean!

Comment: i'm sorry for not unnderstanding but what do you mean by cave and pave?

Comment: Give up and reinstall Windows clean.